# Trying to solve a rubiks cube in Java

Tags: java, heuristics, rubiks-cube

I have developed a class so far that can represent a rubiks cube using a treemap (best way?) each color is mapped to a key 0 - 53. the keys always stay the same and are represented by a 2D view of the cube. I made a rotate90 method that will take a color and rotate that colors face (the middle cubies never move) 90 degrees clockwise. So my question is, how do I implement a good search (maybe A*?) to get this cube to go in the right direction to its goalState(which I initialized as well in the code as a global so I can compare it to the current state). Any feedback or hints in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Here is the code without the rotate 90 method and a checkInput method that just checks if the file text is okay. The input is just a text file that represents the 2D cube and looks like this. The solve method right now is just me messing around and not really getting anywhere.

```
   GGW
   RRG
   RRG
OWWGGOYYR
OGOYYYRBR
YYYRBGRWW
   BOY
   BOB
   BOB
   OGO
   WWB
   WWB

package rubik;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class RubikCube {
final static String FILE_NAME = "rubikTest.txt";
public TreeMap<Integer, Character> goalState;


//swaps two colors given a cube
public static void swapColorValue(int color1, int color2, TreeMap<Integer, Character> rubik){
    char tempColor = rubik.get(color1);
    rubik.put(color1,rubik.get(color2));
    rubik.put(color2, tempColor);
}

//initialize the goal map
public void goalInit(TreeMap<Integer, Character> rubik){
    //initialize the goal state map each rubik.get(magicNumber) is the static center cubie
    TreeMap<Integer, Character> goalMap = new TreeMap<Integer,Character>();
    for(int i =0;i<=8;i++){
    goalMap.put(i,rubik.get(4));
    }
    //the left side
    goalMap.put(9, rubik.get(19));
    goalMap.put(10, rubik.get(19));
    goalMap.put(11, rubik.get(19));
    goalMap.put(18, rubik.get(19));
    goalMap.put(19, rubik.get(19));
    goalMap.put(20, rubik.get(19));
    goalMap.put(27, rubik.get(19));
    goalMap.put(28, rubik.get(19));
    goalMap.put(29, rubik.get(19));
    //the middle
    goalMap.put(12, rubik.get(22));
    goalMap.put(13, rubik.get(22));
    goalMap.put(14, rubik.get(22));
    goalMap.put(21, rubik.get(22));
    goalMap.put(22, rubik.get(22));
    goalMap.put(23, rubik.get(22));
    goalMap.put(30, rubik.get(22));
    goalMap.put(31, rubik.get(22));
    goalMap.put(32, rubik.get(22));
    //right side
    goalMap.put(15, rubik.get(25));
    goalMap.put(16, rubik.get(25));
    goalMap.put(17, rubik.get(25));
    goalMap.put(24, rubik.get(25));
    goalMap.put(25, rubik.get(25));
    goalMap.put(26, rubik.get(25));
    goalMap.put(33, rubik.get(25));
    goalMap.put(34, rubik.get(25));
    goalMap.put(35, rubik.get(25));
    //bottom
    for(int i = 36;i<=44;i++){
        goalMap.put(i, rubik.get(40));
    }
    //back
    for(int i = 45;i<=53;i++){
        goalMap.put(i, rubik.get(49));
    }
    //give it to the global variable
    goalState = (TreeMap<Integer, Character>) goalMap.clone();

}

//Maps a Integer key to a color given a file.
public static NavigableMap<Integer, Character> setup(String file) throws IOException{
    TreeMap<Integer, Character> rubik = new TreeMap<Integer, Character>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        //add each line (without white spaces) to the stringbuilder
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line.trim());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        //convert the stringbuilder(which has all the input from the file) to a char array
        char [] colors = sb.toString().toCharArray();
        //put the key,color into the Treemap.
        for(int i =0; i < colors.length;i++){
            rubik.put(i, colors[i]);
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
    //type Tree map
    return rubik;

    }

public int solve(TreeMap<Integer, Character> rubik){
    int j = 1;
    int check = 0;
    int redMatches=0;
    char [] colors = {'r','g','y','b','o','w'};

    for(int i = 0; i < 100;i++ ){
        if(j==6) j = 1;
        redMatches = 0;
        rotate90(colors[j],rubik);
        if(rubik.get(check)==goalState.get(check)){
            System.out.print("rubik match at: "+i+" with: "+rubik.get(i)+"match at goalState: "+i+" with: "+goalState.get(i));
            redMatches++;
        }

        j++;
    }


    return redMatches;
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    try {
        //check if file input is good
        //System.out.print(new RubikCube().checkInput(FILE_NAME));
        //Map the rubik cube(key,Color)
        RubikCube cubeInst = new RubikCube();
        //make sure to set up the mapping before calling rotate and goalInit    
        TreeMap<Integer, Character> cube = (TreeMap<Integer, Character>) (setup(FILE_NAME));
        cubeInst.goalInit(cube);
        //System.out.print(cubeInst.goalState);
        //rotate90('y',cube);
        //rotate90('y',cube);
        //System.out.print(cube);
        System.out.print(cubeInst.solve(cube));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking for solving algorithms?  Or would that be cheating?  The Wikipedia page on Rubik's Cube has some pointers.  I'm not an expert in this sort of thing, but off the top of my head it seems that since the cube has 6**54 = about 10**42 states, a graph search algorithm isn't going to be feasible.

Comment: Yes, some algorithms I looks at were the A* with a heuristics table (which I am having trouble coming up with) and maybe find a way to solve it layer by layer as I have read that a lot while surfing the web

Comment: A `TreeMap<Integer, …>` is nonsense if your keys run continuously from 0 to a known maximum. An array or `ArrayList` of the value type will do the same when using the key as an index much simpler in source code and more efficient at runtime.

Comment: Okay i will switch that, thanks Holger

Answer (score 1):

I've never written code to solve a Rubik's cube but if you are using a heuristic graph traversal algorithm like A*, I can think of few good heuristics to tell how far away from the goal you are:

1. Number of misplaced cubbies.
2. Summation of how far away each cubbie is from the goal state, possibly using Manhattan distance to tell how far away it is.

The problem is that I don't think you can just use a color for each cubbie state.  You might need to represent the cube as a datastructure positions from some arbitrary angle.  So for example  "top left corner" is the top left corner piece in the goal state (which is also the corner cubbie on the left side and back side...)  Then you will know if your "top left corner" cubbie  is out of place.

Comment: thanks for the input. so you are saying to always look at the cube from the same angle always? for example, always have the white face in the front, the blue to the right, green to the left, etc..

Comment: I think that would make it easier.  The software can see every angle at the same time, it's just keep the cube in a fixed orientation in the datastructure.  This would also let you be able to change the colors since that doesn't affect the algorithm just how users see it.